# Where can I find a free C# eBook?

Tags: c#

Does anyone know a good (free) C# eBook for intermediate programmers? I want something that covers generics, threads, events, delegates, etc.

Comment: Download the e-book downloader tool and download unlimited books  https://programmingbooks.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here are a few open source books:

- [C# Yellow Book](http://www.csharpcourse.com/)
- [C Sharp Programming](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming)
- [Programmer's Heaven C# School Book](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/csharpbook)
- [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)
- [C# Essentials](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/C_Sharp_Essentials)
- [.NET Book Zero](http://www.charlespetzold.com/dotnet/)
- [Data Structures and Algorithms with Object-Oriented Design Patterns in C#](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus6/)

Comment: Beat me by a second haha... +1

Comment: is there a PDF version of the "Data Structures and Algorithms with Object-Oriented Design Patterns in C#". The real PDF, not the HTML converted version of the pdf.

Comment: And there are those books in Russian?

Answer (score 9):

I found these two books fairly useful.

[The C# School Book](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/CSharpBook) - this one covers just about everything you asked about, although it's a bit dated.

and of course, Rob Miles' [C# Yellow Book](http://www.robmiles.com/c-yellow-book/)

Comment: I hate being beaten by a second too.  The answer is still good tho... ;-)